# How to force a RazorPage RedirectToPage to perform a POST instead of a GET

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

For .net core RazorPages there it is common to put code in the OnGet() or OnPost() functions that do some work and then redirect the user to another RazorPage with some data (eg. an anonymous object):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
   // do some work

   // redirect the user to another page
   return RedirectToPage("NextPage", new { user = _user, isComplete = _isComplete });
}
```

The problem is the RedirectToPage *always* redirects with the arguments in the object as a GET, with the arguments visible in the browser address bar:

https://example.com/NextPage?user=Pete&isComplete=true

How can I force the RazorPage to send the redirect request as a POST instead of a get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. A redirect is just a response with a 301, 302 or 307 status code and a `Location` response header that contains the URL you want to redirect to. At that point, it's done. The client can then opt to follow the URL in that `Location` header (if it chooses to - not required). A web browser will follow it automatically by default, but it's going to do so via a GET. There is no way to force a POST.